# add BigDecimal in order to have a running total

Tags: java, numbers, bigdecimal, cumulative-sum

I would like to pick your brians about BigDecimal.. I have a method which is supposed to have a add up a running total amount due. here it is:

```
private BigDecimal addUpTotal(BillRec bill, BigDecimal runningTotal) {
    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(0);

    if (bill.getBillInfo().getBillSummAmtSize() > 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bill.getBillInfo().getBillSummAmtSize(); x++) {
            if ("TotalAmtDue".equals(bill.getBillInfo().getBillSummAmt(x).getBillSummAmtCode().getCode().toString())) {
                result = runningTotal.add(bill.getBillInfo().getBillSummAmt(x).getAmt());                  
            }
        }
    }      
    return result;
}
```

the problem is how do I call this?
meaning when I call it how do I keep track of the total? Note as you can see I am passing the runningTotal as a param but not sure how to keep the value in the method I would call this from.

Comment: Did you really mean to make the result only depend on the *last* match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* you meant it to be something like this:

```
private BigDecimal addUpTotal(BillRec bill, BigDecimal runningTotal) {
    if (bill.getBillInfo().getBillSummAmtSize() > 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bill.getBillInfo().getBillSummAmtSize(); x++) {
            if (...) {
                runningTotal = runningTotal.add(...);
            }
        }
    }      
    return runningTotal;
}
```

You'd call that using a local variable to keep the running total:

```
BigDecimal runningTotal = BigDecimal.ZERO;

for (BillRec bill : bills) {
    runningTotal = addUpTotal(bill, runningTotal);
}
```